# Passing table valued parameters to SP from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, table-valued-parameters

I need help in passing a table valued parameter to the stored procedure. 
We have a layer which is preventing me to specify the parameter type or the SqlDbType in my code.

Below is the code:

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
try
{
    dataTable.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[9]
    {
        new DataColumn("ITEM_INDEX", Type.GetType("System.Int32")),
        new DataColumn("SUBDIV_ID", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32")),
        new DataColumn("DISC_STRT_TS",System.Type.GetType("System.String")),
        new DataColumn("DISC_END_TS", System.Type.GetType("System.String")),
        new DataColumn("DISC_PC", typeof(Decimal)),
        new DataColumn("DISC_SPEC_PC",typeof(Decimal)),
        new DataColumn("ASSOC_CLASS_CD", System.Type.GetType("System.String")),
        new DataColumn("BUSN_CD", System.Type.GetType("System.String")),
        new DataColumn("CREATED_BY",System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    });
    foreach (var item in subDivisionDiscounts)
    {
        dataTable.Rows.Add(
        item.ItemIndex, 
        item.SubDiv, 
        item.FromDate, 
        item.ToDate, 
        item.DiscountPercent, 
        item.SpecialDiscountPercent, 
        item.AssociateClassCode,
        item.BusinessLineCode, 
        item.CreatedBy);
    }
    objHt.Clear();
    objHt.Add("SUBDIVISIONDISCOUNT", dataTable);
    objDs = obj.ExecQuery("ADC_SPCREATE_BULK_SUBDIV_DISCOUNT", CommandType.StoredProcedure, objHt);
```

ExecQuery() is a custom method which takes takes 3 parameters:

1. Query
2. Command Type
3. Hashtable (parameters are added to this
   hashtable and used)

Available overloads for ExecQuery:

```
DataSet ExecQuery(string qryData, CommandType type, Hashtable paramTable);
DataSet ExecQuery(string qryData, CommandType type, Hashtable paramTable, int optionalCmdTimeout);
```

Since I am restricted to use this method, I am not able to pass the SQLDbType to the execute command. Is there a way around this?

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/412802/Sending-a-DataTable-to-a-Stored-Procedure ?

Comment: `obj` is object of which class? is it your custom class, what are available overloads for `obj.ExecQuery` method?

Comment: @NitinSawant Added overloads available.

Comment: then use the one which takes datatable or Object as parameter

Comment: Thank you @NitinSawant. I ended up adding a method with the datatable overload as there wasnt one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
        objHt.Add("SUBDIVISIONDISCOUNT", dataTable);
        objDs = obj.ExecQuery("ADC_SPCREATE_BULK_SUBDIV_DISCOUNT", CommandType.StoredProcedure, objHt)
```

You have to use

```
        objDs = obj.ExecQuery("ADC_SPCREATE_BULK_SUBDIV_DISCOUNT", CommandType.StoredProcedure, dataTable)
```

Dont forget to create type and use it as parameter to your stored procedure

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.PersonType AS TABLE
(
    Name NVARCHAR(50), 
    Age INT
);

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertPerson
    @Person dbo.PersonType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    --your code here
END
```